# thumbnail returning the url of image instead of the picture

Tags: python, django

embedded-video, and the thumbnail should work but it just returns url.

```
Thumbnail: {{ my_video.thumbnail }}
```

should return thumbnail but returns url like http://img.youtube.com/vi/PWgvGjAhvIw/maxresdefault.jpg ...

I think I set everything right. the video gets uploaded but the thumbnail is the only problem. This is their documentation, http://django-embed-video.readthedocs.org/en/v1.1.0/ if anyone can help me figure out why it won't work, thank you very much.

Comment: maybe you need `<img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" >`

Comment: oh good advice, I'll try that

Comment: that's the right answer, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `<img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" >` in HTML and browser shows image.